# get PHP $_FILES array name

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have a html form sending to php script with "post" method (no ajax involved).

In the form i have some `type="file"` fields.

Now in my php script i have a php foreach loop looping through the sent files:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
// Some checks and actions.
}
```

In that loop i want to be able to use the current file array name (which is equal to the name attribute of the upload filled it was uploaded from of course), so i treid:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
// Some checks and actions.
print ($file);
}
```

But that's just echoing "Array".

**Important note:**
My $_FILES array is structured like that:

```
Array
(
    [_pf_photo1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [_pf_photo2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [_pf_photo3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [_pf_photo4] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [_pf_photo5] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [selfimage] => Array
        (
            [name] => IMG_9785.JPG
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpWMOKhn
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 104221
        )

)
```

(`$_FILES` can be structured another way, so to make things clear). so in that example what i want to get in the loop (for the array name part) is:

> _pf_photo1,
>   _pf_photo2,
>   _pf_photo3,
>   _pf_photo4,
>   _pf_photo5,
>   selfimage

Comment: use `print_r` or `var_dump` for debugging. `print` works only with strings.

Comment: foreach($_FILES as $key => $file) {
  echo $key;
}

Comment: Share form code

Comment: That is already suggested in the @George shaw's answer. see comment there.

Comment: Will sharing the form code will be helpful even thought the  `print_r($_FILES)` is shared?

Comment: Both answers below are correct

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer but there is an alternative solution. Use array_keys and foreach that array instead. See here this demo. https://3v4l.org/lWKFs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for if I am understanding your problem correctly.

```
foreach($_FILES as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
}
```

The only other way I can understand this question is if you're incorrectly using print. To print an object/array out with all of its data you can use **var_dump** instead of **print**.

Comment: it guess it will work but then i won't be able to use things like $file[name] in the middle of the loop. am i right?

Comment: You will definitely be able to access array values inside of that loop. In my example it would look like this `echo $value['name'];` because `$value` references an array within `$_FILES` whereas `$key` just references the name of the array.

Comment: Great! Thanks! finally got that (sort of...:)

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are looking to extract your keys

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) { 
  echo $key; // print your array key
  echo $file['name']; // print your name inside that array
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have seen the other one first (i guess that has to do with the way Stackoverflow works) and add some comments so i accepted it, but i did up vote you also. Thank you very much!